# solidity interaction with a struct mapping of a deployed smart contract

Tags: solidity, ethereumjs

I have followed the below code as follows on remix and it works fine but i have an issue when i try to access one of the struct value of a key.The last line of the code doesnt work.

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.6;
contract Product{ 
  struct ProductStruct {  
    bytes32 name;  
    bool status;  
  }  
  mapping(uint => ProductStruct) public productStructs;

  function updateProduct(bytes32 name, uint ID) returns(bool success) {
    productStructs[ID].name = name;
    productStructs[ID].status = true;
    return true;
  }
}

contract External {
  Product p;
  function External(address addr) {
    p = Product(addr);
  }

//below function works
 function readProduct(uint u) constant returns(bytes32 name, bool status) {
      p.productStructs(u);
    return(p.productStructs(u)); // works fine  @Rob Hitchens
  }

// below function doesnt work
  function readProduct(uint u) constant returns(bytes32 name) {
    return (p.productStructs(u).name); // It doesnt work
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The struct being returned works just like multiple return values. You need to use a destructuring assignment to grab the two values:

```
function readProduct(uint256 u) external view returns (bytes32 name) {
    bool status;
    (name, status) = p.productStructs(u);
    return name;
}
```